# VB.NET Can someone inject code into my database through my compiled application?

Tags: vb.net, security

My scenario is as follows, a .NET 4.0 Solution with several projects (one host and some dlls), one (dll) in particular making use of the MySQL .NET Connector in order to only call upon stored procedures. I've also signed all my assemblies with a private key.

I'm curious if a hacker could somehow obtain the password to the database user from the connection string (even though that user only has permission to EXECUTE).

Also I'm curious whether a hacker would be able to find out the stored procedures I call on and whether he could Select/Insert/Delete arbitrarily with the use of my stored procedures.

All this with the presumption that the hacker only has a copy of the compiled solution.

Comment: "I'm curious if a hacker could somehow obtain the password to the database user from the connection string" - yes. Use integrated security where possible.

Comment: How would one protect against that? What does 'integrated security' mean?

Comment: http://www.google.com.au/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=windows+.net+integrated+security&oq=windows+.net+integrated+security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have hard-coded the user name and password in your code, or even if you store the credentials in an encrypted file, but the encryption key is hard-coded in your code, it is easily hackable because .NET assemblies are not compiled to machine code.  When you build a .NET assembly, it converts your VB.NET code into MSIL code, which is just a lower level programing language which is still easily readable.  Microsoft provides a free tool (as part of the .NET Framework SDK) called MSIL Disassembler which allows you to easily view all the MSIL code for any compiled assembly.  There are many tools available which allow you to easily take the MSIL code and "decompile" it to VB or C# code.  You'd be amazed at how easy it is to reproduce your original code with a .NET decompiler.  If the PDB's are available, the output is shockingly similar to the original code.  So, unless you are using some third-party code obfuscation or assembly encryption tool, your "compiled" assemblies are very easily reverse engineered.  Usually this isn't a big deal, but if avoiding hacking is a high concern, you certainly shouldn't be putting any secrets in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot SteveDog, this is very good to know. Do you recommend any "3rd party code obfuscation or assembly encryption tools"?

Comment: No, I don't have any recommendations.  Visual Studio 2005 used to come with a free third-party obfuscation tool called "Dotfuscator".  It was a very simplistic obfuscator, though.  I researched it years ago for my last job and ultimately we decided not to use any of them.  They all have some pretty significant down-sides.  Obfuscation makes stack-traces pretty worthless, so debugging can be very difficult without using additional de-obfuscation tools from the same vendor.  The encryption tools usually cause wrinkles in your deployment scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Are you confident that all of the code in the project is safe from things like SQL Injection vulnerabilities and Local File Inclusion vulnerabilities (and will remain so, as it evolves)?

Comment: I'm confident against SQL Injection, I'm unsure of the steps to take to prevent Local File Inclusion